# New folder in public_html in Direct Admin

Tags: php, opencart, directadmin

I have an open-cart website using for about a year. I work with PHP 5.6 and direct admin. I want to add a blog system to my website. So I created a folder name `blog` in my `public_htm` folder and uploaded a WordPress files in blog directory. By pressing `mydomian.com/blog` the WordPress installation does not appear. What I am doing wrong?

This is the error shown in the error log:
`No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

But there is `index.php` in the directory. Have I add something to `.htaccess.txt`? What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Are you accessing mydomain.com/blog/index.php?

Comment: Have you actually gone through the WordPress installation process?

Comment: When I enter mydomain.com/blog/index.php? a white screen in shown and nothing is shown. Wordpress installation process is not stating.

Comment: @StephenFrosty please check the APACHE/HTTPD  `error.log` files, there would be some error in the files causing the `blank page` to appear.